# How can I "stream" a section of my webpage to another window?

Tags: javascript, websocket, streaming

I want to stream a certain container on my webpage to another window.

The setup is similar to a Point of Sale system. ie an operator-facing display and a second customer-facing display.

The operator-facing display will have a window with all the toolbars, menus etc. While the customer-facing display will only show a certain container from the first operator-facing window.

As below: The Operator Display will contain the full webpage content. While the customer display will only contain the #output container.

Operator Display

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <ul>
         <li><button>Action 1</button></li>
         <li><button>Action 2</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="output">
   //OUTPUT GOES HERE
</div>
```

Customer Display

```
<div id="output">
   //OUTPUT GOES HERE
</div>
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put "stream" in quotes, I assumed that you are looking for different solutions for this problem.

[image]

In browsers you can easily open a new window and control it from main page, I've created a small snippet which implements a case, where on one window you can add items and display them on another one.

These lines are most important:

```
const posWindow = window.open("about:blank", "customerDisplayWindow", "height: 50,width: 50");
posWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<h2>Items</h2><ul id="item-display"></ul>';
```

You could come up with much cleaner solution than modifying document but you get the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/jhd5L8wa/1/

I suggest reading MDN page about `Window.open()` (especially third argument, windowFeatures) to learn more about how opened window will look and behave.